# Host .NET Core console app on Heroku

Tags: .net, heroku

I tried to host my net core console app (telegram bot) on heroku, using various buildpacks and deploiyng through git.
It always fails on building. Most of them say that app is not compatible with the build pack (for example, official one), and some say that app cannot be compiled from .csproj file

Is there a clear instruction what to do to deploy .net core console app to heroku?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/ They don't support .NET Core yet.

Comment: I have crated a small sample app. It is on [Github](https://github.com/rasodu/AspnetCoreOnHerokuSample). Check if that helps you. But it may not be exactly what you are looking. It is not using build pack. It is directly using docker instead. So there is a lot of manual wiring.

Answer (score 1):

I have build with https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack. U need to change your application to have a Startup.cs at the root of your project.

Comment: I appreciate your work!
The funny thing, your buildpack does work for webapps, and I think it doesn't work for workers.
Or I just don't understand simple things yet.